# How to build static libraries?

Tags: linux, static-libraries, libraries

I need to build a static library to create a binary. I am using ubuntu 15.04 and I need libdevmapper static library. I am sorry I couldn't be more clear as I have absolutely no clue how to do that. I installed libdevmapper-dev, it only installs .so not .la. Any pointers on how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Find where the libdevmapper.so is linked to your application. There should be something like `-ldevmapper`. replace that with  `-Bstatic -ldevmapper`

Comment: Get a copy of libdevmapper.tar.bz2.  Run dist/configure with option --disable-shared.  Pray.

Comment: Download the LVM sources https://www.sourceware.org/lvm2/

`git clone http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/lvm2.git`

    $ cd lvm2
    $ ./configure --enable-static_link --prefix=$PWD/build/
    $ make device-mapper

Find the libdevmapper.a in `lvm2/libdm/ioctl/`

Answer (score 0):

You might first want to take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) to get some idea about static libraries.

First you need to create your object code from your source file.

```
gcc -Wall -c test1.c test2.c
```

Then you need to use the `ar` command to generate the library file.

```
ar -cvq libtest.a test1.o test2.o
```

Comment: He wants to build lidevmapper as static library